# Google Datastore go client, storing dynamic data

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

Our application provides functionality which enables a customer to create dynamic forms and business rules. We recently decided to explore Google infrastructures so we don't have to spend time tweaking and adjusting our infrastructure.

Thus far, we have managed well using a NOSQL database such as arangodb to store random data sets through their JSON HTTP REST APIs, that stores any sort of data structure, so long as it is a valid JSON. However, Google data store go client library and Datastore doesn;t work with JSON and also imposes rules like no silce []type, no map map[type]type failing with errors such as `datastore: invalid Value type` e.t.c

I explored option of implementing PropertyLoadSaver interface load/save functions with modifications to create PropertyList and Property to crate a []Property. Case below Collection is `type Collection map[string]interface{}` which holds an sort of data set

```
    func (m Collection) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
    data := []datastore.Property{}
    for key, value := range m {
        if util.IsSlice(value) {
            props := datastore.PropertyList{}
            for _, item := range value.([]string) {
                props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: key, Value: item})
            }
            data = append(data, datastore.Property{Name: key, Value: props})
        } else {
            data = append(data, datastore.Property{Name: key, Value: value, NoIndex: true})
        }
    }

    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(data)

    return data, nil
}
```

Yes, we can create a struct which we can populate based on map data and save that to Datastore. We were however wondering if there possibly is an easier way to just receive a map and save it to Datastore with no added complexity.

Alternative

```
type Person struct{
 Name string
 Surname string
 Addresses []Address
 ...
}

type Address struct{
  Type string
  Detail string
}
```

This `map[string]interface{}{Name:"Kwasi", Surname:"Gyasi-Agyei", Addresses:...}`  can than be marshaled into above struct to be saved by Datastore go client lib.

Am however more interested in taking advantage of PropertList, []Property, unless that route is unnecessarily complex. What am basically asking is, which is the most appropriate route that offer the same type of flexibility as a schemaless database.